# Show time in the title of a plot, matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm working with unsteady state problems, that is problems that depends of time. And I'd like to know how to show computation time on a graph, something like this:

[image]

What I have found so far is:

```
tic
% PROCESS
toc
```

that tells me the time a process lasts. I'm not looking for tic toc.

Do you know how can I show how the time changes in seconds onto the graph?

Comment: Please show us some effort to get us start to help you. Have you tried some code. Please post that. Please have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I tried to improve the wording of the question, towards what I think you are intending to ask. Did I grasp it correctly?

Comment: thanks,  but no. What I want to do is to show  how the variable t (time) changes, and I want to show it in the title of the graph

Comment: The time value is the one set by your solution algorithm. Can you simply do a `num2str(t)` and concatenate that into the title somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example: (Please read: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/title.html)

```
tic
% PROCESS
t = toc;

x = 1:10;
y = 1:10;
plot(x,y)
title({'Your title...'; strcat(['t=',num2str(t),'s.'])})
```

Output

[image]